# How do I get AngularJS to bind to HTML set by jQuery?

Tags: angularjs

For example, in the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NFNvc/28/

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.test1 = 'Hello world';
    $scope.test2 = 'Hello new';
});

$(function() {
    $("#text").html("{{test2}}");
});
```

AngularJS is not binding to the variable 'test2. How do I get it to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can include the jQuery lines within the controller, then use the scope variable rather than curly braces.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.test1 = 'Hello world';
    $scope.test2 = 'Hello new';

    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery("#text").html($scope.test2);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example from the angularjs documentation on how to update angular when you update the DOM outside of the angular scope.

```
var $div = $('<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">{{content.label}}</div>');
$(document.body).append($div);

angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
  var scope = angular.element($div).scope();
  $compile($div)(scope);
});
```

Full documentation is [at the bottom of this page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector).